# Comparing values for guessing game in java gui

Tags: java, user-interface

I am trying to make a GUI in java and I have two JTextfields. One textfield displays the question which is a hashmap of the form (question : answer) where question is stored as key and answer as value. The question is displayed in one textfield called aTextField and the user enters the answer in answerField. Now I want to check if user provided the correct answer. Here is my code:

```
guessAA.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            String answerFieldValue =answerField.getText().toUpperCase();
            int idx = indexGenerator.nextInt(19);
            String key = FULL_NAMES[idx];
            aTextField.setText("Guess this   " + key);

            if(answerFieldValue != null && !answerFieldValue.isEmpty())
            {
                System.out.println("your input  " + answerFieldValue);
                System.out.println("correct answer   " + myMap.get(key));
            }
```

Now the output for this is : 
    your input  C
    correct answer   T
    your input  T
    correct answer   W
    your input  W
    correct answer   G

So as you can see my question is always stored as one next so I am never able to compare. Can anyone please help? Thanks

Comment: Well, `nt idx = indexGenerator.nextInt(19);` looks suspicious, but without more context, it's impossible to know

Comment: To me, it "seems" like you're moving to the next question before validating the current question, so you seem to be looking at the next question's answer instead of the current questions's answer

Comment: yes this is exactly what is happening. I am very new to java so I am unable to point out where the fix should be made

Comment: Well, you need to maintain information the current question, this you would use to validate the current question/answer and then AFTER that, update the question information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, it "seems" like you're moving to the next question before validating the current question, so you seem to be looking at the next question's answer instead of the current questions's answer.

This would suggest what you need, is some kind of reference to the current question which is been asked.

Now, because I don't have access to your overall code, all I can do is provide a conceptual overview of what you could do...

```
public class YourAwesomeGuessingGame extends ... {
    private String currentQuestionKey;

    public YourAwesomeGuessingGame() {
        // Seed the current question key with the first question
        currentQuestionKey = ...;
        // Update the UI

        guessAA.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                String correctAnswer = myMap.get(key));
                String answerGiven = answerField.getText().toUpperCase();
                // Compare the results, take appropriate action
                // Seed the current question key with the next question
                currentQuestionKey = ...;
                // Update the UI
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something along the lines of:

```
if(myMap.get(key).equals(answerFieldValue)){
   //answer was right
}else{
   //answer was wrong
}
```